# How to display meetings related to contact in a subpanel -SuiteCRM

Tags: relationship, suitecrm

I am using SuiteCRM Version 7.9.2. I didn't change the relationship between Meetings and Contacts (many to many). I can see contacts invited to the meeting in the contacts subpanel (forMeetings), but I can't see any meetings listed in meetings subpanel when I view a contact. Actually, I don't even have a Meetings subpanel there. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging, I found that this is because there is no subpanel module defined for Meetings in meetings_contacts relationship. The meetings related to contacts can be seen under Activity subpanel. Hope this helps.